# How to make a PDF downloadable so it doesn't open up in new window

Tags: asp.net, pdf, download

I found a link here on Stack that explains how to do this, but it explains it only in PHP lingo.  I want to have links on my website to a PDF file so that it automatically goes to a "save as" screen instead of opening up in a web page form.  This way, the end user will be able to download it easier, because a lot of my clients don't know how to do a file/save as on a web page.

So I want to have a link such as:

```
<a href="brochure.pdf" target="_blank">Download Brochure</a>
```

then it'll go right to a "save as" box and allow the client to save the PDF brochure to his/her computer without opening up another web page.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you remove the target, and the contain in the header the  `attachment;`, then you have what you ask for.

Comment: thanks Aristos .... I got rid of the target, and that helped.   I appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you replace "brochure.pdf" with an asp.net page that contains the following code in the Page_Load event, you'll get the desired behavior:

```
  string filename = "brochure.pdf";
  Response.ContentType = "image/pdf";
  string headerValue = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename);
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);
  Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filename));
  Response.End();
```

Another approach would to include a link button that has the above code in it.  For security purposes, be sure you validate the filename however you assign it so users don't gain access to arbitrary files.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to respond, Tom.  I'm working on it.  It seems that your answer is similar to the answer Icarus gave.  Being a non-programmer, I made a page, DownloadMgr.aspx, but I'm unsure as to where I would put the code you suggested because I don't know where the page_load even is.  Again, I appreciate your time in helping!

Comment: Your aspx page has a supporting DownloadMgr.aspx.cs file. This will have a page_load event in it. The above code is C#. Just put the above code in it and it will work.

Comment: Hey Tom ... my DownloadMGR.aspx.vb file just has this as the code behind:  Partial Class products_DownloadMgr
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class

Comment: But you and Icarus definitely set me on the right path, and I'll figure this out via trial and error.  Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out, and I'll get this working.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can't force a file download from a hyperlink alone (or reliably using Javascript) unless you add the Content-Disposition header to the response; therefore, one way to address this issue and always force a file download could be to have an intermediate page that will add the header for you.

Your link, therefore, has to become something like this:

```
<a href="DownloadMgr.aspx?File=brochure.pdf" target="_blank">Download Brochure</a>
```

And `DownloadMgr.aspx` should be something like this:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    if(Request.QueryString["File"]!=null) 
    {  
       if(Request.QueryString["File"].Contains("pdf")))
          Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; //varies depending on the file being streamed
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +  Request.QueryString["File"]);
   Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["File"]));                
}
```

A better approach, though, is to create an HTTPHandler to do the same thing. You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306095/345490) for more details on how to do it. One of the benefits of creating an HTTPHandler is that it doesn't involve all the processing, initialization and so forth, that's required for a regular `aspx` page.

**Sample with full code:**

```
<%@ Language=C# %>
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>Download Manager</title>
</head>
   <script runat="server" language="C#">
       void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
           {
               if (Request.QueryString["File"] != null)
               {
                   if (Request.QueryString["File"].Contains("pdf"))
                       Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; //varies depending on the file being streamed
                   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Request.QueryString["File"]);
                   Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["File"]));
               }
           }
       }
   </script>
   <body>
      <form id="form" runat="server">

      </form>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

## VB.NET version

```
<%@ Language="VB" %>
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>Download Manager</title>
</head>
   <script runat="server" language="VB">
       Sub Page_Load()
           If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then

               If (Request.QueryString("File") IsNot Nothing) Then
                   If (Request.QueryString("File").Contains("pdf")) Then
                       Response.ContentType = "application/pdf" 'varies depending on the file being streamed
                   End If
                   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Request.QueryString("File"))
                   Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString("File")))
               End If
           End If
       End Sub
   </script>
   <body>
      <form id="form" runat="server">

      </form>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

Now save the above code as `DownloadMgr.aspx` and drop it inside your website.

Comment: Hi Icarus.  It seems like you and Tom had similar ideas, just slightly different ways of going about it.  I did make a DownloadMgr.aspx page, but being a non-programmer, I'm kinda confused on where to put the coding you offered because I don't know where the page_load event it.  Thank you very much for taking the time to respond.  I'll keep trying!

Comment: Thank you very much Icarus.  It's telling me that <script runat="server" language="vb"> conflicts with the property "form" in the base class page and should be declared in shadows.

Comment: The ifs are underlined in VS 2010 and say they can't appear outside a method body / multiline lambda, and the responses are underlined in squiggly blue and say declaration expected.  But you definitely set me on the right path -- I'll figure this out heuristically via trial and error.  Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out.  I'll get this working!

Comment: @JasonWeber I apologize, the code I posted was missing a `}` with was causing some errors. I've updated the code once more. Copy and paste it again.

Comment: Hey @Icarus -- I tried to run the revised code through Telerik's code converter, since my site is in vb, and it gives me this error:          CONVERSION ERROR: Code could not be converted. Details:

-- line 2 col 4: "}" expected

Please check for any errors in the original code and try again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with this line:   void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @JasonWeber sit tight, will post the VB.NET version soon

Comment: @JasonWeber VB.NET version posted.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference if anyone ever needs to know, I found the answer using a combination of Tom's and Icarus's answers.  I just had to convert some C# to VB.  Anyway, my hyperlink is:

```
<a href="DownloadMgr.aspx">Download Brochure</a>
```

My DownloadMgr.aspx.vb code behind is like this:

```
Partial Class products_DownloadMgr
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim filename As String = "USS_Exact_Scan_Introduction.pdf"
    Response.ContentType = "image/pdf"
    Dim headerValue As String = String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename)
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue)
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filename))
    Response.[End]()

End Sub

End Class
```

Thank you very much Tom and Iracus for taking the time to help!